# Acyclic compact Lie groups of dimension 3

Tags: algebraic-topology, lie-groups, homology-cohomology, smooth-manifolds

Are there any examples of compact connected Lie groups with vanishing first homology groups in dimension $3$ different from $S^3$?

Comment: What do you mean by "acyclic"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$S^3$ isn't [acyclic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acyclic_space), if by acyclic you mean having vanishing homology in positive degree; in fact no compact Lie group of positive dimension is acyclic, because they're closed and orientable and hence have nontrivial top homology.

The complete list of $3$-dimensional compact connected Lie groups is

- $T^3$
- $SU(2) \cong S^3$
- $SO(3) \cong \mathbb{RP}^3$.

There are lots more disconnected ones, e.g. any of these times a finite group. Of these, $SU(2)$ is the only one that's simply connected. Is that what you meant?